# Using Entity Framework to connect to SQL Server CE (.SDF file)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I can successfully connect to an `.mdf` file with Entity Framework. My connection string is as below:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\FacilitySecurity.mdf;Integrated Security=False;Connect Timeout=30"
```

On my computer I can connect and use `.mdf` file. But when I run my application on another computer, there's an error that about SQL Server service. I think I must use `.sdf` file instead of `.mdf` file.

But how can I connect to an `.sdf` file with Entity Framework? And which application or services must be installed in any other computer for run my application?

Comment: First thing to be clear about: should each user have their own database? Or should they connect to a shared database?

Comment: each user have a local database

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server (probably you mean Express Edition) and SQL Server CE that use `.sdf` files are completely different products that have nothing in common except "SQL" letters in the name. SQL Server CE is not a server application, it is just a library for embedding.

To use SQL Server CE, for instance with Entity Framework as alternative data provider, you can add appropriate NuGet packages to the project and change connection string (and actually to add a dozens lines in application configuration file). But be careful: functionality of SQL Server CE engine is much more limited.

To use LocalDB on other computer you need to install SQL Server.

Answer (score -1):

You can try it,follw this description and install the EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact package.

【Install Entity Framework 6 from NuGet】
To get the latest and greatest Entity Framework 6 bits, always install from NuGet. And thanks to the amazing package dependency resolution features of NuGet, just install the single required package, and the remaining packages will be installed as dependencies. In this case, the only thing that is missing from the EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact package (which depends on SQL Server Compact 4 and EF6) is a DbProvider registration in the app.config file, that enables you to run without the SQL Server Compact runtime installed in GAC and machine.config. To fix this “"misssing link”, I have created the [EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.PrivateConfig/), which simply adds the missing config entries and in turn depends on all other required packages.

In other words, simply install the EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.PrivateConfig package. Right click the References folder in your project, and select Manage NuGet Packages. Search for the package name and install it. And all required packages and references will be installed. (I am working on getting these config entries added to the base EntityFramwork.SqlServerCompact package, in order to make things more streamlined)